# Do gases behave ideally near the critical temperature?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

In class, my TA said the closer the temperature of a gas is to the critical temperature, the more ideal it is. I'm struggling to understand this, as I thought more ideal behavior occurs at high temperature and low pressure. I am probably missing something really obvious :(

Comment: You're right. Pressure and temperature interact in a compressible gas. So any sweeping statement about either pressure or temperature alone is spurious.

Comment: I'd say critical behavior is _the farthest possible_ from ideal.